# Get popular products has been sold?

Tags: mysql, database

I am using using subquery to get popular products that has been sold in the `order_products` table.

```
SELECT 
   products.name, 
   (SELECT count(product_id) FROM order_products WHERE order_products.product_id = products.id) as total FROM products 
ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 10
```

This query seem to work fine but I feel there has to a better way instead of using sub-query?

I have tried using `GROUP BY order_products.product_id` with `count()` but I get aggregate sql error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refactor your subquery to a join, something like this.

```
SELECT 
    products.name, 
    COUNT(*) AS count
FROM
   products
JOIN
   order_products ON order_products.product_id = products.id
GROUP BY
   products.name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 10
```

This is pretty much equivalent to what you have. But it expresses your intent in a way that many SQL programmers find easier to read.  And, the query planners in many MySQL versions will do a good job with this, where they might not with the subquery version.

**Edit** The columns mentioned in `GROUP BY` should also appear in the `SELECT` clause.  If you want both the product id and the product name to appear, use this kind of query.

```
SELECT 
    products.id, products.name, 
    COUNT(*) AS count
FROM
   products
JOIN
   order_products ON order_products.product_id = products.id
GROUP BY
   products.id, products.name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 10
```

You may be able to get away with saying `SELECT products.name` and `GROUP BY products.id`.  But for that to work you depend on either a deprecated feature of MySQL or an optional feature of SQL99.  Many programmers like to avoid such things.  Read this for more info.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: Thank you. Shouldn't it be group by order_products.product_id?

Comment: Could be, but probably should not be. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Following sql will help you out.

> SELECT products.name, count(*) FROM order_products INNER JOIN 
>   products ON order_products.product_id = products.id GROUP BY
>   products.name ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 10;

Since you are selecting product.name, you should use the same field in your **group by** clause.

You can learn the actual reason for this by reading rule 1 in below link:
http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=664143&seqNum=6